# rosserial_xbee Unable to sync with device

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to connect to an arduino via rosserial_xbee using xbee s1 and I am receiving this error:

```
Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I have seen similar posts in this forum but suggested solutions have not worked for me.

These tutorials work for me:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

I can reproduce the error following these steps:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_xbee/Tutorials/Example%20Network

I have also tried various branches of rosserial such as the indigo branch etc.
Rosserial works via usb and I have tested that the xbees work not using rosserial.

System:
Ubuntu 14.04,
Arduino IDE 1.6.5,
ROS Indigo.

Hardware:
Arduino Uno,
XBee S1 (x2),
XBee explorer,
XBee shield.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216191/rosserial_xbee-unable-to-sync-with-device/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-24**:
Does it have to be the Spark Fun Xbee shield? I'm using the Seeed Studio one. Has anyone had success with that shield?

I've now done a fresh install of Ubuntu, Ros and Arduino. Followed the tutorials to the letter. Still same result. So wondering if it's a hardware issue.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-24**:
Would also be interested to know what versions of ROS and Arduino people are using for this to work.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-25**:
Just tried it with the SparkFun Xbee shield, still not working for me.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-25**:
One point of difference is that I am not using the pro version xbee as shown in the link. I wouldn't have thought that would be the issue. I don't want to buy 2 of those just to find out it's not. Anyone got this to work on non pro s1 xbee?

**Comment by [hemant T](https://answers.ros.org/users/23015/hemant-t/) on 2016-01-11**:
Hello K1B3,
I am facing exact same problem and I am using same ROS version and Ubantu as you. Here is the problem I reported.
http://answers.ros.org/question/223035/ros-serial-xbee-unable-to-sync-with-device/
Please help me understand what you did to solve this issue.
Appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problems with my Arduino and my Mbed. They mostly seem to arise out of "Arduino/Mbed Hardware.h" and the pins used to communicate with the Xbee.
Which pins does your shield use to communicate with the Arduino?

As far as I know the default config for the sparkfun sheild uses the software serial port, maybe if you switch it to use UART TX,RX you may have better luck.

---

Originally posted by [stormswordx](https://answers.ros.org/users/24518/stormswordx/) with karma: 26 on 2015-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-10-19**:
stormswordx my friend - you are the man!!!
Sorry for the slow response, I was working on something else and only just had a chance to test.
Many thanks!

**Comment by [hemant T](https://answers.ros.org/users/23015/hemant-t/) on 2016-01-11**:
Hello K1B3, I am facing exact same problem and I am using same ROS version and Ubantu as you. Here is the problem I reported. http://answers.ros.org/question/22303... Please help me understand what you did to solve this issue. Appreciate it.
Thanks.